# When is a Store's Inventory Determined?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

When is the inventory of a Store set?

- at the beginning of the sector
- right before the store is visited
- some other time

Will visiting the same store multiple times offer different buy options or more fuel/missles/drones?

Comment: Store inventory is locked once visited, I haven't done enough save-scumming to know about when the inventory is generated, but it is likely on store creation. (Entering the sector, or completing the quest that creates it.)

Comment: @Sconibulus Save-scumming? Why not virtual-machine-state-snapshot-scumming?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

## Inventory is determined when you first arrive at the store node

The store inventory is generated **when you jump to the store node on the map**. Revisiting a store node that you've already visited will not change the inventory of that store.

### I tested this by doing the following

- Start the game
- Proceed until you see a "store" node
- Save and exit
- Go to My Documents\My Games\fasterthanlight and make a copy of continue.sav
- Start the game
- Visit the store
- Exit the game
- Restore continue.sav
- Start the game
- Visit the store

On the first visit I got a store containing the following;

[image]

On the second visit I got a store containing the following;

[image]

Since these two inventories are different, and my save was from before visiting the node, the store must be generated as you visit the node.

Comment: Are the store contents at all dependent on the state of your ship? (Current weapons, crew, etc.)

Comment: That's a completely different question that would require a significant amount of testing to confirm but based on what we know already a good assumption would be that everything is random.

Comment: I am not an alot.

Comment: No you are not , you're kalina.

Answer (score 2):

It can be implied that the store's inventory is set a the beginning of the sector since that is when the game generates all the nodes for that sector. Although it can be when you are entering a store node, it's hard to say for sure.

Edit: See kalina's answer

Visiting the same store multiple times will not yield different items.

Comment: Not all stores are necessarily generated when the nodes are - some stores can be created by events.